# Описание привилегии "правка вопросов и ответов"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Ошибка/опечатка в описании - вероятно, пропущен предлог *"для"* в тексте
"*... и будет видно не только **для** автора, но и **для** того...*".
Кроме того, возможно, правильнее добавить:
"*Сообщение обновится, и **исправление** будет видно...*", ведь само сообщение будет видно и без принятие правки, а речь идет об обновленном, исправленном варианте оригинального сообщения.

Также, пропущен пробел в тексте "*«изменен 3 дня назад»).Редактирование*" перед словом *редактирование*.

Скриншот прилагаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Также предлагаю слегка переписать текст ради согласования предложений и более внятного смысла:
- оригинал
*Кроме того, пользователи с данной привилегией также могут просматривать предложенные правки т. е., которые вы предложили раньше. Данные изменения находятся в состоянии ожидания, пока не наберут достаточно голосов, и либо получить одобрение, после чего правки вступят в силу, либо их отклонят - и правки сбросятся. Для достижения результата достаточно двух голосов за или против, кроме Stack Overflow , где требуется три голоса.*
- мой вариант
*Кроме того, **другие** пользователи с данной привилегией также могут просматривать предложенные **вами** правки - **те**, которые вы предложили раньше. Данные изменения находятся в состоянии ожидания, пока не наберут достаточно голосов, и либо **получат** одобрение, после чего правки вступят в силу, либо их отклонят - и правки сбросятся. Для достижения результата достаточно двух голосов за или против, **в отличии от Stack Overflow /гиперссылка на so.com/**, где требуется три голоса.*

Comment: в первом случае как раз все правильно. После редактирования вопроса/ответа показывается кто его последний редактировал, а не только автор

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После комментария [Grundy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy) переосмыслил текст. Мой вариант исправления следующий:

"*Сообщение обновится, и будет **виден не только автор, но и тот**, кто внёс последние изменения.*"

---

Текст "*Кроме того, пользователи с данной привилегией*..."

предлагаю исправить следующим образом:

"*Кроме того, **другие** пользователи с данной привилегией также могут просматривать предложенные **вами** правки - **те**, которые вы предложили раньше. Данные изменения находятся в состоянии ожидания, пока не наберут достаточно голосов, и либо **получат** одобрение, после чего правки вступят в силу, либо их отклонят - и правки сбросятся. Для достижения результата достаточно двух голосов за или против, **в отличии от Stack Overflow /гиперссылка на so.com/**, где требуется три голоса.*"